# What synchronism can I use?

Tags: c#

I'm working in C# and i'm searching for a mechanism to synchronize my application.

I have a function to manage anomaly in my Application, working on multi-thread. When an anomaly is raised, a function is called, making some treatment and asking for user to check.

If a new anomaly is raised while the first is in progress I want to wait for the first and doing nothing after (function has been executed for the first)

How can I do that properly ?

My draft :

```
private void onAnomaly(enumAnomaly err)
{
    if (anomalyInProgress)
        //wait
        return;
    else
        anomalyInProgess = true;
        //do something
        anomalyInProgess = false;
}
```

Comment: With a [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: a lock is waiting for the first one but execute code after

Comment: I didn't get this part - `and doing nothing after (function has been executed for the first)`? Do you mean to say that while the first anomaly is being processed then you want to wait before new anomaly is processed. Once first anomaly has finished then you want to to start processing the newly arrived anomaly. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: @RBT I'll try to explain more (sorry for bad English). In my application I have many type of anomaly and one function to remove all. Anomaly A and anomaly B are removed by the same function (`onAnomaly`). at the end of this function, a pop-up is opened and ask for user to check. If an anomaly B is raised while anomaly A is in `onAnomaly`, B have to wait end of `onAnomaly` (user acknowledge) but not call `onAnomaly` because user have already valid the pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Interlocked.Exchange method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d3fxt78a(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Edit** according to your comments, you need the other functions to wait. You can do this by adding a lock object.

```
private int anomalyInProgress = 0;
private Object _lock = new Object();

private void onAnomaly(enumAnomaly err)
{
    //Here, the value of anomalyInProgress will be set to 1, but
    // Exchange return the value before the change.
    // So if it was 0 before, it means nobody is already executing this code
    //and we can safely enters
    if (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(anomalyInProgress, 1))
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            //do something

            //we reset the value of anomalyInProgress so the next one can enter in safely
            Interlocked.Exchange(anomalyInProgress, 0)
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        //I cannot take the lock directly, because I could be taking it before the 'True' condition.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        lock (_lock) //This will wait for the 'True' condition to finish
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I say to Amey Kamat, the `lock` will execute `do something` twice (or more). I want to what for `do something` but not redo after

Comment: Don't forget to set anomalyInProgress back to 0 when completed, else any future calls will be discarded as well.

Comment: @SuperPeanut I just test this solution and I don't feel  it wait for the first function. Maybe I can mix this solution with `ManualResetEvent` but is there efficient and secure ?

Comment: @FacticiusVir Update the answer, made a small mistake on second Exchange call

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you (you forgot the keyword `ref` but it's a details ^^)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with lock, maybe not the best but it seems to work

```
private object anomalyLock = new object();
private Queue<enumAnomaly> anomalyQueue = new Queue<enumAnomaly>();

private void onAnomaly(enumAnomaly err)
{
    anomalyQueue.Enqueue(err);

    lock (anomalyLock)
    {
        if (anomalyQueue.Count == 0)
            return;

        //do something

        // UserAck

        anomalyQueue.Clear();
    }
}
```

Is there a best way ?

Comment: Risky! Two anomalies can get enqueued at once before you take the lock. You process only one at the front of the queue and then clear the entire queue. You might not even process other anomalies in the queue. I think this is a possibility unless you reveal how are you going to process the queue in your `//do something` section. And still your original problem statement was the fact that you don't want to begin processing any anomaly until the previous anomaly isn't fully processed. Isn't it?

Comment: In that case I don't really care if I have more that one anomaly before the lock. But you right, there is a risk, if an anomaly rise between the user ack and the `queue.Clear`. But I have nothing better

Comment: Did you try the solution I provided with Interlocked.exchange ? I think it does exactly what you need...

Comment: I've tried but the `Interlocked.Exchange` did not wait the end of my function (the user ack)

Comment: @A.Pissicat Edited again, so now I wait for the end

Answer (score -1):

When anomaly is raised, the function that you call can be locked

```
object lockObj = new object();
lock(lockObj)
{
    //function called once anomaly raised
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can be wrong but for me the lock is waiting for `function called once anomaly raised`. When the first call is over the second one start to call it. It almost that I want but I what to call just one time the function